# How to obtain TF using only TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining

I have a code like this one:

```
 corpus = [
        'This is the first document.',
        'This document is the second document.',
        'And this is the third one.',
        'This document is the fourth document.',
        'And this is the fifth one.',
        'This document is the sixth.',
        'And this is the seventh one document.',
        'This document is the eighth.',
        'And this is the nineth one document.',
        'This document is the second.',
        'And this is the tenth one document.',
    ]

    vectorizer = skln.TfidfVectorizer() 
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
    tfidf_matrix = X.toarray()
    accumulated = [0] * len(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

    for i in range(tfidf_matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(len(vectorizer.get_feature_names())):
            accumulated[j] += tfidf_matrix[i][j]

    accumulated = sorted(accumulated)[-CENTRAL_TERMS:]
    print(accumulated)
```

where I print the `CENTRAL_TERMS` words which get the highest tf-idf scores over all the documents of the corpus.

However, I also want to get the `MOST_REPEATED_TERMS` words over all the documents of the corpus. These are the words which have the highest tf scores. I know I can obtain by simply using `CountVectorizer`, but I want to use only `TfidfVectorizer` (in order to not performing first the `vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)` for the `TfidfVectorizer` and then the `vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)` for the `CountVectorizer`. I also know that I could use first `CountVectorizer` (to obtain tf scores) followed by `TfidfTransformer` (to obtain tf-idf scores). However, I think that there must be a way to this only using `TfidfVectorizer`.

Let me know if there is a way to do this (any information is welcome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `TfidfVectorizer` does the `l2` normalization after multiplying the `tf` and `idf`. Hence we cannot get the term frequency, when you have the `norm='l2'`. Refer [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/16f4ac90f/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1430-L1435) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/16f4ac90f/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1810-L1812)

If you can work without norm, then there is a solution.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import pandas as pd 

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None) 
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
n = len(features)
inverse_idf = sp.diags(1/vectorizer.idf_,
                       offsets=0,
                       shape=(n, n),
                       format='csr',
                       dtype=np.float64).toarray()

pd.DataFrame(X*inverse_idf, 
            columns=features)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can done your work like this

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
        'This is the first document.',
        'This document is the second document.',
        'And this is the third one.',
        'This document is the fourth document.',
        'And this is the fifth one.',
        'This document is the sixth.',
        'And this is the seventh one document.',
        'This document is the eighth.',
        'And this is the nineth one document.',
        'This document is the second.',
        'And this is the tenth one document.',
    ]
#define the vectorization model
vectorize = TfidfVectorizer (max_features=2500, min_df=0.1, max_df=0.8)

#pass the corpus into the defined vectorizer
vector_texts = vectorize.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
vector_texts
```

- You have to change `max_features, min_df, max_df` values for to get best fit for your model.In my case

```
out[1]:
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        ]])
```